# With type hinting, how do I require a key value pair when the key has an invalid identifier?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typeddict

With type hinting, how do I require a key value pair in python, where the key is an invalid identifier?
By required I mean that the data is required by type hinting and static analysis tools like mypy/pyright + IDES.
For context: keys with invalid python identifiers are sent over json.

- for example the [key name class](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB/blob/a757716ddd520e608f6e1d973dabd49b344d033a/public/openapi/read/search.yaml#L79)

A dict payload with key value pair requirements must be ingested. See below for the additional requirements.

Here is a sample payload:

```
{
  'a': 1, # required pair with valid identifier
  '1req': 'blah', #required key with invalid identifier
  'someAdditionalProp': [] # optional additional property, value must be list
}
```

The requirements for the ingestion of this dict payload are are:

1. there is a valid identifier 'a', with type int that is required
2. there is an invalid identifier '1req' with type string that is required
3. additional properties can be passed in with any string keys different from the above two and value list
4. all input types must be included so TypedDict will not work because it does not capture item 3
5. in the real life use case the payload can contain n invalidly named identifiers
6. in real life there can be other known keys like b: float that are optional and are not the same as item 3 additional properties. They are not the same because the value type is different, and this key is a known literal (like 'b') but item 3 keys are strings but their value is unknown

What I want is a class or function signature that ingests the above payload and meets the above type hinting requirements for all required and optional key value pairs. Errors should be thrown for invalid inputs to the class or function in mypy/an IDE with type checking turned on.

An example of an error that would work is:

```
Argument of type "tuple[Literal['otherReq'], None]" cannot be assigned to parameter "args" of type "OptionalDictPair" in function "__new__"
  "tuple[Literal['otherReq'], None]" is incompatible with "OptionalDictPair"
    Tuple entry 2 is incorrect type
      Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "list[Unknown]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

A naive implementation that does NOT meet requirements would be:

```
DictType = typing.Mapping[
    str,
    typing.Union[str, int, list]
]

def func_with_type_hinting(arg: DictType):
    pass

func_with_type_hinting(
    {
        'a': 1,
        '1req': 'blah',
        'someAdditionalProp': None
    }
)  # static analysis should show an error here, someAdditionalProp's type is wrong
```

Comment: I'll be honest, even with your answer below, I have _no idea_ what you are talking about here and it is a bit frustrating. Do you have some function with some parameter that you want to annotate? This does not clarify anything: _"By required I mean that the data is required by type hinting and static analysis tools"_ Required **for what**? What are you trying to express? Can you please just include a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show the output (maybe of Mypy) you are getting and also the output you _want_ to get?

Comment: My question has a sample payload of what is to be ingested. I just added a section `What I want is a class or function signature that ingests the above payload and meets the above type hinting requirements` saying what I want to get

Comment: That is still not a MRE. You want a class **or** a function? And then what? What do you want to do with that? I know you think you are explaining yourself here, but you are really not. I would love to help or at least give my two cents, but I just don't understand your goal here. But you do you.

Comment: Not trying to be unclear here. I added more info showing a sample function func_with_type_hinting ingesting a payload that should throw a type error and I gave an example error.

Comment: Can you clarify why `TypedDict` didn't work for you? It sounds like exactly what you need based on the code sample. It can handle both invalid identifiers and optional properties. Is it because you _don't_ know ahead of time what the names of the optional keys are?

Comment: Yes it's because you don't know the name of the unknown optional keys. TypedDict does not allow for additional keys that the typeddict does not know about. It allows known required keys + typed values, optional known keys and typed values. It does not allow optional unknown keys and typed values.

Comment: If you don't know the name of the optional keys ahead of time, you can't do static type checking.

Comment: If you want to verify data against a schema that isn't known before runtime, look at using something like https://json-schema.org, not type hints.

Comment: > If you don't know the name of the optional keys ahead of time, you can't do static type checking.
@chepner Yes you can. Option 1 in my answer does this.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't use type hints; you're just using the same *values* that function annotations use to provide type hints.

Comment: Option 1 constrains the inputs to frozenset_with_length to meet the requirements with type hints on required_1, required_2, and *args. How are those not type hints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254095/discussion-between-spacether-and-chepner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 (frozenset of tuples) is my favorite and meets all requirements. The only caviat is that arguments must be passed in required then optional order.

Options that I know are:

1. Use a frozenset of tuples to require that the required args are passed first, then the optional args.
   This assumes that rather than passing the dict in as a dict instance a frozenset of tuples of key value pairs are passed in instead.

- the frozenset ensures no duplication
- the tuples define the unique key value pairs

```
OptionalDictPair = typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.LiteralString, list]

RequiredDictPairs = typing.Union[
    typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.Literal['a'], int],
    typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.Literal['1req'], int]
]

ReqAndOptionalDictPairs = typing.Union[
    typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.Literal['a'], str],
    typing.Tuple[typing_extensions.Literal['1req'], int],
    OptionalDictPair
]


_T_co = typing.TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)

class frozenset_with_length(frozenset[_T_co]):
    def __new__(
            cls,
            required_1: RequiredDictPairs,
            required_2: RequiredDictPairs,
            *args: OptionalDictPair) -> typing.Union[frozenset_with_length[RequiredDictPairs], frozenset_with_length[ReqAndOptionalDictPairs]]:
        req_args = (required_1, required_2)
        if not args:
            return super().__new__(cls, *req_args) # type: ignore
        all_args = tuple(req_args)
        all_args.extend(args)
        return super().__new__(cls, *all_args) # type: ignore

tuple_items = frozenset_with_length(*(
    ('a', 1),
    ('1req', 1),
    ('additionalProExample', []),
))
```

- pro: all required keys must be present, values checked too
- con: required parameters must come first, then optional ones

2. use a function and move the invalid arg value into a union in kwargs
   `def some_fun(*, a: int, *kwargs: typing.Union[list, str]):`

- pro can pass in unpacked dict
- con: no requirement on invalid required key name

3. use a function and use *args to define the values for the invalidly named parameter
   `def some_fun(a: int, *args: str, *kwargs: list):`

- pro: required args not shown in kwargs
- con: arguments must be passed in specific order
- con: missing required arg key definition
- con: *args could be omitted by the invoker

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `TypedDict`, which can be defined "functionally" rather than declaratively when the keys are, in fact, not valid identifiers. For example, replace the invalid

```
class Payload(TypedDict):
    a: int
    1req: str
    someAdditionalProp: list[str]
```

with

```
Payload = TypedDict('Payload', {'a': int, '1req': str, 'someAdditionalProp': list[str])
```

Then use `Payload` as the type hint for your function's parameter.

```
def func_with_typehinting(d: Payload):
    ...
```

Comment: This will not work because we do not know the name of the unknown keys ahead of time. The key someAdditionalProp is not known. See requirements 3 + 4

Comment: Then you can't use type hints: they are, by definition, part of the static syntax of the language, not data that you learn at runtime.

Comment: Yes you can, see option 1 in my solution.